# sql server merge two records if first have null or blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tables say A

I want to merge two records in one say with record Id 100 and 101

```
id    Col1   Col2    Col3 ....... Col100   parent_Id
100   null   some                 val      33
101   xyz    abc     pqr                   100
=============================================== result should be
      xyz    some    pqr         val
```

Condistion:

1. If first record have the value (not blank) then show from first record means 100
2. If first record have NULL or blank then show from second record

I can solve it by using the case statement for every columns by join, like this

```
Case When ISNULL(R1.Col1, '') = '' Then R2.Col1 ELSE R1.Col1 END
```

Is there any trick which can save me to write the case for every column?

Comment: You have to write a separate expression for each column, but the `COALESCE()` function provides a more concise way to express what you seem to want.

Comment: Coals will check for nulls not for blank values.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, even so, `COALESCE(NULLIF(R1.Col1, ''), R2.Col1)` is still a little shorter, and possibly a little cheaper.

Comment: `COALESCE(ISNULL(R1.Col1), ''), R2.Col1)` this will always pick first parameter

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, yes, I wrote the expression incorrectly, and subsequently fixed it.

Comment: If your mission is just shorten then this is also valid `iif(isnull(col1, '')='', col2, col1)`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any trick which can save me to write the case for every column?

There is no trick in T-SQL to avoid needing to write a separate *expression* for each column in the merged result.  You can, however, use expressions other than `CASE` expressions, some of which offer small concision advantages and possibly small runtime advantages.  Two such expressions are presented in the comments on your question.

If you really want to avoid writing separate expressions, and you have a lot of tables for which you want to do this kind of merging, then you could consider writing a user-defined function for it, or even just doing it with an external program, either one of which should be able to express the idea of processing each column the same way.  Yours would need to be a pretty big problem before something like this made sense, though.